# value outside of valid range on numeric field: NaN

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I want to track how many times a user clicks on a certain button called `Reject`. So I created a counter field that will be updated whenever the `Reject` button is clicked. The counter I created is called `Num_of_Rejects_Tier3__c` and it's a field of type Number.

So here is a snippet of the onClick JavaScript button:

```
var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
caseObj.Num_of_Rejects_Tier3__c=caseObj.Num_of_Rejects_Tier3__c+1;
```

I don't know why but I get the following error:

> value outside of valid range on numeric field: NaN

What does it say that it isn't a number and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is not a number because new Case instance doesn't have any value. I am not sure if `Num_of_Rejects_Tier3__c` will have any existing value based on existing logic. Try below logic where we are checking if value is a number or not.

```
var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
caseObj.Num_of_Rejects_Tier3__c= (isNaN(caseObj.Num_of_Rejects_Tier3__c) ? 0 : caseObj.Num_of_Rejects_Tier3__c )+1;
```

Note that, because you are creating new Sobject record. So, Num_of_Rejects_Tier3__c won't have any value and initialized to `null` each time/click. You must update the records and query existing count to make it work.